For arbitrary function $g$, how can we prove $\frac{\partial g(\widehat{f})}{\partial f } = \widehat{\frac{\partial g({f})}{\partial f } }$
Notation
Let $\widehat{f}$ be a linear integral operator relating to a quantity $f$ defined by
$$\overline{f} = \int\Psi(q)^*\left(\widehat{f}\Psi\right)(q)\,dq  ,$$
where $\overline{f}$ is the mean of quantity $f$.
Context
I'm reading Landau and Lipshitz Quantum Mechanics. On pages 55-56, there is a proof to show that two operators are related by a constant of proportionality.
$$
\widehat{v} =\widehat{p} /m.
$$
The proof given therein relies on that fact that
$$
 \frac{\partial \widehat{f}^2}{\partial f } = 2\,\widehat{f} \tag{1}.
$$
Clearly $dx^2/dx = 2x$, but, to my mind, that does not necessary imply Eq. 1.
Question
How can we prove that for an arbitrary function $g$
$$\frac{\partial g(\widehat{f})}{\partial f } = \widehat{\frac{\partial g({f})}{\partial f }  }?$$

Are sure that’s what they used?

@Egor Larionov, I checked again. Yes, I am sure. It also comes up in the uncertainty relations where $\frac{\partial \widehat{x}}{\partial  x } = \widehat{1}$.

I get it is unclear (or you got confused) how they define the derivative of an operator. In (16.5) they write $\partial f/ \partial p$ on the right hand side. What they mean is $\partial f/ \partial p = (\partial f/\partial p)(\hat p) $.
